# JOINING 2 MYSQL queries

Tags: php, mysql, datatables

I have two queries below, the first one is query for my **DataTables** and the second one is for the regular HTML table.

The first query is:

```
SELECT a.*, b.personnel_name 
FROM `work_order` as a 
LEFT JOIN `personnel_master_data` as b ON a.`reg_no` = b.`reg_no` 
WHERE a.`status` = 'Continue' 
GROUP BY `id` 
$sOrder 
$sLimit
```

I executed the query in my php file and DataTables works perfectly, and now the second query:

```
SELECT d.`wo_number`, SUM(d.`crew_est` * d.`manhour_est`) AS 'crew_kali_manhours', 
    CONCAT(((SUM(d.`crew_est` * d.`manhour_est`) / 
            (SELECT SUM(c.`crew_est` * c.`manhour_est`) 
             FROM `work_sheet_machine` AS c 
             WHERE c.`wo_number` = '$wo_number')) * 100)) AS `progress` 
FROM `work_sheet_machine` AS d 
WHERE d.`status` = 'FINISH' AND d.`wo_number` = '$wo_number'
```

The second query seems working good on regular HTML Table with GET parameters. I need to join the second query with the first query and use that query on **DataTables** server side processing file. I'm having problem on joining `progress` field from second query into first query.

Comment: what you mean by common? `wo_number` are exist in both of `work_sheet_machine` and `work_order` tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the second query into the first one as a subquery.

```
SELECT a.*, b.personnel_name, e.crew_cali_manhours, e.progress
FROM `work_order` as a 
LEFT JOIN `personnel_master_data` as b ON a.`reg_no` = b.`reg_no`
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT d.`wo_number`, SUM(d.`crew_est` * d.`manhour_est`) AS 'crew_kali_manhours', 
        CONCAT(((SUM(d.`crew_est` * d.`manhour_est`) / 
                (SELECT SUM(c.`crew_est` * c.`manhour_est`) 
                 FROM `work_sheet_machine` AS c 
                 WHERE c.`wo_number` = d.wo_number)) * 100)) AS `progress` 
    FROM `work_sheet_machine` AS d 
    WHERE d.`status` = 'FINISH'
    GROUP BY wo_number
) AS e ON e.wo_number = a.wo_number
WHERE a.`status` = 'Continue' 
GROUP BY `id` 
$sOrder 
$sLimit
```

Use `INNER JOIN` instea of `LEFT JOIN` if `work_sheet_machine` always has matching rows for the rows in `work_order`.

Comment: it's working. OMG! thank you so much. You saved my life. :-D